# Partial derivative involving integration to find critical values

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

Suppose, we have a function $X(t)=\dfrac{exp[b(t)^Tc+b(t)^TAu]}{\int_a^bexp[b(s)^Tc+b(s)^TAu]ds}$

s or t is variable belong to (a,b). Practically we take finite points in this range. c and u are p* 1 vector, b(t) is p* n matrix and A is p* p matrix. Is it possible to differentiate $X(t)$ it with respect to c and find the critical values of c? I know basic rules about matrix differentiation, but I am wondering how to proceed with the integration extract c from that? After begining I end up with

$\dfrac{\partial X(t)}{\partial c} =0$

$=>\int_a^bexp[b(s)^Tc+b(s)^TAu]ds* [b(t)^T]=\int_a^bexp[b(s)^Tc+b(s)^TAu] b(s)^Tds$

How to go further? Can we proceed this way or we need to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}$Define
the all-ones vector $\o$ and the variables
$$\eqalign{
w &= Au + c \quad&\implies\quad dw = dc \\
p &= \exp\left(B^Tw\right) \quad&\implies\quad P = \D(p),\,p=P\o \\
h &= \int_a^b p\,ds \quad&\implies\quad H = \D(h),\,h=H\o \\
J &= \int_a^b PB^T\,ds \\
}$$
and their differentials
$$\eqalign{
dp &= PB^Tdc \\
dh &= J\,dc \\
}$$
Now define the vector of interest and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
x &= H^{-1}p \\
dx &= H^{-1}dp + \c{dH^{-1}}p \\
  &= H^{-1}dp - \c{H^{-1}dH\,H^{-1}}P\o \\
  &= H^{-1}PB^Tdc - H^{-2}P\,dh \\
  &= \left(H^{-1}PB^T - H^{-2}PJ\right) dc \\
  &= H^{-2}P\left(HB^T - J\right) dc \\
\grad{x}{c} &= H^{-2}P\left(HB^T - J\right) \\
}$$
NB: Since $\{H,dH,P,dP\}$ are diagonal matrices, they commute with each other.

Setting the gradient to zero yields
$$\eqalign{
HB^T &= J \\
\left[\int_a^bP\,ds\right]\cdot B^T &= \int_a^bPB^Tds \\
B\cdot\left[\int_a^bp\,ds\right] &= \int_a^bBp\,ds \\
}$$
This confirms your result, and dividing through by
$\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right)$
it looks like some sort of *mean-value theorem* for the $p$ vector.
$$\eqalign{
B\,\big\langle p\big\rangle &= \big\langle Bp\big\rangle \\
}$$

If we insert the explicit functional dependence on the time-like variables
$$\eqalign{
B(t)\cdot\left[\int_a^bp(s)\,ds\right] &= \int_a^bB(s)p(s)\,ds \\
}$$
note that the LHS depends on $t$ while the RHS does not. This implies that $B$ is not a function of time, or that the RHS is zero and the integral on the LHS is orthogonal to $B(t)$ at all times $-$ which implies that the integral itself is zero $-$ which implies that **both** integrals are zero.

Comment: Thanks, I have another similar with little bit more advance problem I have posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4141501/matrix-differentials-to-estimate-the-critical-value-from-an-equation-that-involv  can you help with this question.